# Using Htmlagility pack getting attribute values

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Using `Htmlagilitypack` I can get the attribute value for one tag by using following code:

```
public string parseinput(HtmlDocument HtmlDocument)
{
     try
     {
            return HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type=""text""]").Attributes["value"].Value;
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          string x= ex.ToString();
            return "Error is... '"+x+"'" ;
     }
 }
```

When it gets first value, it stops executing and gives that value, but I need to get all those text type values as output.

For this what do I need to do?

Comment: what is the format of output you want?

Comment: it should return name and values of the type text. Take example of input tag type is "hidden". so it should return the name and values of all those tags which type of hidden ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode`

```
return String.Join(",", HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@type=""text""]")
                         .Select(n=>n.Attributes["value"].Value)
```

If you need both input type and value

```
var inputs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input").Select(n => new { 
                 Type = n.Attributes["type"].Value, Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value }).ToList();
```